# Ruby Regex Help

Tags: ruby, regex

I know a little bit of regex, but not mutch. What is the best way to get just the number out of the following html. (I want to have 32 returned). the values of width,row span, and size are all different in this horrible html page. Any help?

```
<td width=14 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">32</font></td>
```

Comment: The best way is to use a parser not regular expressions. :-)

Comment: @Erik: In principle yes, but for quick and dirty screenscraping regex are usually a viable tool.

Comment: I would use a parser, but the HTML is too badly formatted.

Comment: Well, your example certainly is valid, though :-). And HTML parsers usually are designed to deal with erroneous markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
>(\d+)<
```

Or, if you desperately want to avoid using capturing groups at all:

```
(?<=>)\d+(?=<)
```

Comment: This returns >32< but I guess I could just do string.match(/>(\d+)</).match(/\d+/)

Comment: @bun: Well, you'll find the `32` in the first capturing group ... I edited the answer to include an example which doesn't need the group, though.

Answer (score 2):

Please, do yourself a favor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'nokogiri'

require 'test/unit'
class TestExtraction < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_it_extracts_the_number_correctly
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<td width=14 rowspan=2 align=right><font size=2 face="helvetica">32</font></td>')
    assert_equal [32], (doc / '//td/font').map {|el| el.text.to_i }
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree. Going after HTML content with regex is a lot more error prone over the long term compared to using a parser.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
<td[^>]*><font[^>]*>\d+</font></td>
```

Comment: This will certainly match the string above, but won't do anything to extract the `32`.

Comment: Well, if Ruby's regexp synatx is borrowed from Perl, then you need to put \d+ in parentheses. And then use match()[1]